# What is the purpose served by the context_uri query param in the OIDC/oAuth2 authorization request sent by Firebase to federated identity providers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, wso2-asgardeo

I have been trying to use Asgardeo as a federated identity provider in Firebase. I followed Firebase's documentation and managed to develop a sample application to perform authentication. However, during authentication, I noticed that the authorization request contains a query param called `context_uri` that is set to the origin of the application. Asgardeo blocks this request since this query param contains a URL. I tried the same flow with other federated identity providers such as Facebook and could still see the `context_uri` in the request. I searched OIDC and oAuth2 resources and realized that `context_uri` is not a standard query param. So, what purpose does it serve? Can this be removed from the authorization request?

Here is the authorization request that was blocked:

```
https://dev.api.asgardeo.io/t/<tenant>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client-id>&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>&state=<state>&scope=openid%20email%20profile&nonce=8<nonce>&context_uri=<app-origin>
```

I tried to use Asgardeo as a federated IdP in Firebase but the authorization request was blocked because of the context_uri query param.